# set multi level functions in by pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with these king of datas

```
group1;group2;group3;amount1;amout2
100;10;2017;250.0;230,0
100;10;2017;220.0;210,0
100;10;2018;50.0;230,0
100;10;2018;220.0;210,0
100;20;2017;250.0;230,0
100;20;2017;220.0;210,0
100;20;2018;250.0;230,0
100;20;2018;220.0;210,0
200;10;2017;250.0;230,0
200;10;2017;220.0;210,0
200;10;2018;250.0;230,0
200;10;2018;220.0;210,0
200;20;2017;250.0;230,0
200;20;2017;220.0;210,0
200;20;2018;250.0;230,0
200;20;2018;220.0;210,0
```

I need to calculate the variance between year (*) and for each group level and for each amount column (amount1, amount2....)

(*) variance_by_amount (var): amount1_2017 - amount1_2018
(*) variance_% (var%) : variance_by_amount / amount_2017

i tried pivot_table, and group_by but did not find any clue.

Exemple:
(amount have change for the exemple)

```
group1;group2;group3;amount1;amount2
100
      10  2017  500.00  300.00
      10  2018  300.00  200.00
          var  -200.00    0.00
          var%   -0.40   -0.33

      20  2017  600.00   400.00
      20  2018  800.00   600.00
          var   200.00   200.00
          var%    0.33     0.50

      all  2017 1100.00   700.00
      all  2018 1200.00   800.00
          var    100.00   100.00
          var%    0.09     0.14
200
      10  2017  500.00  300.00
      10  2018  300.00  200.00
          var  -200.00    0.00
          var%   -0.40   -0.33

      20  2017  600.00   400.00
      20  2018  800.00   600.00
          var   200.00   200.00
          var%    0.33     0.50

      all  2017 1100.00   700.00
      all  2018 1200.00   800.00
          var    100.00   100.00
          var%    0.09     0.14

all  
           2017 2200.00  1400.00
           2018 2400.00  1600.00
          var    200.00   200.00
          var%    0.09     0.14
```

Comment: how are you getting data in your example? As far as I understood that you are applying `grouby` on `group1, group2, group3` but confusion here is how you are getting values of `amount1` and `amount2` as in first row `500 and 300`. How did you get these values?

Comment: These values comes from a dataset. They need to by groupby group1, group2, group3

Comment: `100;10;2017;250.0;230,0    100;10;2017;220.0;210,0` after applying groupby `group1, group2, group3 ` which aggregation function you are applying to `amount1, amount2`. Moreover, you have defined ` variance_by_amount (var): amount1_2017 - amount1_2018 ()` so for first `var`, it should be `200` not `-200`.